# Element hr not allowed as child of element ul in this context. (Suppressing further errors from this subtree.)

Tags: html, css

My recent code is as below:

Now my problem is putting "hr" tag directly it works very well but gives site validation error. So I changed my code as below. :

```html
<nav>
            <ul>
       <li id="one"><a href="#HOME" id="a" class="active">HOME</a></li>
                            <li id="two"><a href="#ABOUT" id="b">ABOUT</a></li>
       <li id="three"><a href="#SERVICE" id="c">SERVICE</a></li>
       <li id="four"><a href="#COLLECTIONS" id="d">COLLECTION</a></li>
       <li id="five"><a href="#CONTACT" id="e">CONTACT</a></li>
                          
            <hr/>               
   </ul>
            </nav>
```

```css
body{background:#CCCCCC;}
    nav{width:100%;margin:0 10px;padding: 38px 0;}
    nav li{padding:0;}
    nav ul li{display: inline;text-align: center;}
    nav a{display: inline-block;width: 15%;padding: .75rem 0;margin: 0;text-decoration: none;font-family:'leelawadeeregular';font-size: 18px;           color:#e81b64;}
    #one a:hover,.active,#two a:hover,#three a:hover,#four a:hover,#five a:hover{color:#ffffff;}
    #two:hover ~ hr {margin-left:18%;text-decoration:underline;}
    #three:hover ~ hr {margin-left:33.5%;text-decoration:underline;}
    #four:hover ~ hr {margin-left:48.5%;text-decoration:underline;}
    #five:hover ~ hr {margin-left:64%;text-decoration:underline;}
    nav hr {height: .25rem;width:10%;margin:0px 0px;background:#e81b64;border: none;transition: .3s ease-in-out;}
```

```html
<nav>
                <ul>
           <li id="one"><a href="#HOME" id="a" class="active">HOME</a></li>
                                <li id="two"><a href="#ABOUT" id="b">ABOUT</a></li>
           <li id="three"><a href="#SERVICE" id="c">SERVICE</a></li>
           <li id="four"><a href="#COLLECTIONS" id="d">COLLECTION</a></li>
           <li id="five"><a href="#CONTACT" id="e">CONTACT</a></li>
                              
               <li> <hr/></li>
       </ul>
                </nav>
```

Now its not giving site validation error but my css animation of sliding underline is not working. So please give me solution of it.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you need to add the li in your css like this :

```
    #two:hover ~ li hr {margin-left:18%;text-decoration:underline;}
    #three:hover ~ li hr {margin-left:33.5%;text-decoration:underline;}
    #four:hover ~ li hr {margin-left:48.5%;text-decoration:underline;}
    #five:hover ~ li hr {margin-left:64%;text-decoration:underline;}
```